# Passing the updated value in html hidden input

Tags: php, javascript

I am making a project regarding about online examination in which admin can be able to add test and after that it will show it in the div. Inside the div it will show all the list of selected test and therefore, he can be able to delete any test by simple clicking a cross sign. So, I am stuck in the process in which if I am deleting any test and after that I am submitting a form then it is showing me all the test including the deleted test. Below are my code:

```
<?php  
    if(isset($_POST['addTest']))
    {  
        echo "<br>";
        echo "SELECTED TEST LIST";
        echo "<br>";
        echo '<div style="backfround:white;padding:5px;border:2px solid;overflow:scroll;height:100px;">';
        $fruitList = implode(', ', $_POST['jdb']);
        $jdStore = explode(',',$fruitList);
        $jdValueStore = ""; 

        for($i=0;$i<count($jdStore);$i++)
        {
            $testShowState = "select testId, testName from test where testId= '$jdStore[$i]'";
            $testShowQuery = mysql_query($testShowState);
            $testShowFetch = mysql_fetch_array($testShowQuery);

            echo  $jdValueStore[] =  "<div class='divClass'>

                                          <p>".$testShowFetch['testName']."</p>
                                          <img src='images/deletebttn.gif' alt='delete' class='deleteDiv' />
                                      </div>";
        }

        echo '</div>';
    } 

    $jdTotal = serialize($jdValueStore);
    $encoded = htmlentities($jdTotal);

?>
<input type="hidden" name="jdStoreValue" value="<?php echo $encoded; ?>">
<input type="submit" class="button add" value="Save" style="width:auto;" id="addSave" onclick="myAddSave()" name="myAddSave" >
```

On The page where I am getting the values:

```
$jdStoreValue = unserialize($_POST['jdStoreValue']);

for($i=0;$i<count($jdStoreValue);$i++)
{
    echo $jdStoreValue[$i];
}
```

It is showing me all the test. I don't want a deleted test.

Comment: What i able to understand is that it is getting the value when executing the page that is why it is showing all the test. So how can i be able to get only the test which is not deleted by the admin using any script?

Comment: Your code needs `Tab`+`Shift`

Answer (score 0):

You should remove serialize code.

```
if(isset($_POST['addTest']))
{  
    echo "<br>";
    echo "SELECTED TEST LIST";
    echo "<br>";
    echo '<div style="backfround:white;padding:5px;border:2px solid;overflow:scroll;height:100px;">';
        $fruitList = implode(', ', $_POST['jdb']);
        $jdStore = explode(',',$fruitList);
        $jdValueStore = ""; 

        for($i=0;$i<count($jdStore);$i++)
        {      
            $testShowState = "select testId, testName from test where testId= '$jdStore[$i]'";
            $testShowQuery = mysql_query($testShowState);
            $testShowFetch = mysql_fetch_array($testShowQuery);
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="fruitList[]" value="'.$testShowFetch['testId'].'" />';
            echo  $jdValueStore[] =  "<div class='divClass'>

                <p>".$testShowFetch['testName']."</p>
                    <img src='images/deletebttn.gif' alt='delete' class='deleteDiv' />
                </div>";
         }

        echo '</div>';
} 
<input type="submit" class="button add" value="Save" style="width:auto;" id="addSave" onclick="myAddSave()" name="myAddSave" >
```

Comment: I am able to hide my division from the page by using the jquery scirpt  before. The problem is that when the page executed all the test list was stored in a $jdTotal  and then after encoded it i passed it to the hidden input form so thats why even if i will delete a list then it is not updating the test list.

Comment: @ANerd In your PHP code you get `fruitList` array which you directly use.

Comment: If i will remove serialize function then i will not be able to pass the array value in the hidden input field as it will show me array on getting it on the other page by using for loop

Comment: @ANerd I have added this code `echo '<input type="hidden" name="fruitList[]" />';` for passing hidden field.

Comment: What will be the benefit of passing fruitList[] when all i want is to get the test list in the other page?

Comment: @ANerd you should only pass `Ids` or `name` in hidden field.Not entire `html div`

Comment: I can pass anything in hidden field using an array. I am able to get all the test list on the other page using my code but want that deleted list will not be get in the other page

Comment: I have added `echo '<input type="hidden" name="fruitList[]" value="'.$testShowFetch['testId'].'" />';` for passing `testId` in hidden field for it getting non deleted Tests

Comment: I want that it will get only the test which has not deleted by the admin on my action page. I think it can be done through ajax but the thing is that i don't know much about ajax. Really don't have had a time for it..

Comment: No you don't want Ajax for it through this code you get those `Testids` which are not deleted.You should try this @ANerd

Answer (score 0):

bind jquery onclick event to cross button which will reduce the count of exam on deleition also update the hidden field.